# Kubernetes Nginx upload large file 400 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: file, nginx, kubernetes, cors, kubernetes-ingress

When I keep default of `proxy_body_size: 8m` of nginx. I can't upload the file size > 8M. Then I configure nginx annotation like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "ingress-name"
  annotations:

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
```

So, I can upload the files > 8M now. But, I have tried to upload CSV file about 50m, I got an error

> Failed to load https://api.domain.xxx/import: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://web.domain.xxx/' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Anyone can help me to upload the large maximum file is 100m?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to upload the file from a different domain than the one specified in the ingress. It may be the same domain but a different port, protocol (http/https), prefixed with www., etc

By default, the browser doesn't allow those requests, because of security concerns. To allow them you should enable CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Fortunately, it's quite easy to enable CORS in an ingress, just add the following annotations to your api's ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://web.domain.xxx"
```

More info about those annotations [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)

Comment: I got error `Failed to load https://api.domain.xxx/import: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://web.domain.xxx, https://web.domain.xxx', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://web.domain.xxx' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Pls recheck that my small file can update, and frontend and api are same domain (`https://web.domain.xxx` and `https://api.domain.xxx/import`)

Comment: Just updated with the domain info, note that those annotations should be added to de api's ingress,

Comment: For development purpose you can just accept all origins with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"`

Comment: I got the same error above, both `"*"` and `"https://web.domain.xxx"` cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180748/discussion-between-workwe-and-ignacio-millan).